# Python Selenium: Quit Browser if Idle

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a list of headless Chrome webdrivers the following way:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
browsers = {}

def add_browser(browser_id):
     browsers[browser_id] = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=options)
     browsers[browser_id].get(URL)
```

However, I would like to close browsers that have been active and idle for too long. How may I implement that?

If it helps - this is being used for a Flask app.

Comment: How do you detect is idle or are you able to do it??

Comment: I haven't been able to detect idle browsers. I believe some timestamps would be needed, but can't think of how to implement that for the browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

def add_browser(browser_id):
     browsers[browser_id] = {
          browser: webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=options),
          last_active: datetime.now()
     }
     browsers[browser_id][browser].get(URL)
     // do some stuff... scrape links? navigate through pages? input text?
```

Then when writing your script in the `//do some stuff` section, you can now do one of two things:

```
// "check in" to confirm the session is still active
browsers[browser_id][last_active] = datetime.now()
```

```
// during a loop that you are worried about getting stuck in due to the browser being idle
idle_time = datetime.now() - browsers[browser_id][last_active]
if idle_time.seconds > maximum_idle_time:
     browsers[browser_id][browser].quit()
```

Comment: Thank you. The last snippet may not fit well for my program (assuming that it is a loop). Like I mentioned in one of the comments that timestamps would be needed, that is exactly what you've done and improving on this, I would refactor `add_browser()` to remove the browser with the earliest timestamp before adding another browser.

Comment: You're welcome. What is the use case here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm working on a web-scraping chatbot created with Flask. :)

Comment: You might be interested in this selenium scraping platform I built in flask. It abstracts away all of the necessities (saving scraped data, progress/error logs, exporting saved data, managing simultaneous scraper sessions etc). Really useful for building and testing scrapers before deploying them in more “industrial” contexts.

https://github.com/chrispalmo/auto-scrape

If you do check it out, I would love to hear what you think, and would be happy to help you get it set up.